# Python/Numpy reshaping 2D array into 3D array based on first column value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file that i am reading in as follows:

logic_blocks = map(str.split, logic_blk_file);

And essentially this file has the columns as such:

Circuit #, Logic Type, etc.etc.

Where I want to create a 3D array. The first index should be Circuit #, the second index is the row or text file line and the third is the item within the text file line.

I want the first index to obviously be the circuit #, so an arbitrary reshape will not work. It will need to be based on the Circuit # value.

I can do this with for loops but is there a way to avoid them?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give a small representative input example and its expected output. Also a snippet of how you would do it with loops, or at least the idea of it, would be helpful to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: One thing at a time.  First read the file (that will be done with a loop, line by line).  Converting the resulting array(s) to your 3d might be possible with a few array operations, but we need to see clearly what you doing.